# RxJS -- How to make a timer trigger by click a button when using RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

```js
@Component({
    template: ` <div>
                    <a *ngIf="!sending" (click)="send()">Send</a>
                    <span *ngIf="sending" >{{seconds}} s</span>
                </div>`,
    selector: 'password-reset-form'
})
export class PasswordResetFormComponent implements OnInit {

    sending:boolean = false;
    seconds:number = 60;
    counterObservable = new Subject();


    constructor(public authService:AuthService, public router:Router, public formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.counterObservable.subscribe(()=> {
            this.seconds --;
        }, null, ()=> {
            this.seconds = 60;
            this.sending = false;
        });
    }

    send() {

        this.sending = true; 
        this.counterObservable.next(Observable.interval(1000).take(60));
    }
}
```

Hey,I try to using ng2 and RxJS to make a timer,when I click the send button,it would display a 60s timer,but I spent a lot of time and still don't know how to use RxJS to do it.
I would appreciate very much if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
send() {

    this.sending = true;
    let subscription = Observable.interval(1000).take(60).subscribe(()=> {
        this.seconds --;
    }, null, ()=> {
        this.seconds = 60;
        this.sending = false;
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

I solved it,like this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@Component({
    template: ` <div>
                    <a *ngIf="!sending" (click)="send()">Send</a>
                    <span *ngIf="sending" >{{seconds}} s</span>
                </div>`,
    selector: 'password-reset-form'
})
export class PasswordResetFormComponent implements OnInit {

    sending:boolean = false;
    seconds:number = 60;    

    constructor(public authService:AuthService, public router:Router, public formBuilder:FormBuilder) {

    }

    ngOnInit() { }

    send() {

        this.sending = true;
        Observable.timer(1000, 60)
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.seconds--;
            }, 
            err => {},
            () => {
                this.sending = false;
                this.seconds = 60;
            });  
    }
}
```

Comment: It‘s wrong,I want every 60 seconds can click once,and also it can not stop automatically,but anyway,thanks for you answer.